# NSTimeinterval problem for date in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am converting the date into NSTimeinterval like the code below:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval currentyInterval = [appDelegate setTimeInterval:currentDate];    
NSDate *expiryDate = [appDelegate setReverseDate:warrObj.expiredOn];


NSTimeInterval expiryInterval = [appDelegate setTimeInterval:expiryDate];
//Here I am getting the nil value and exception is generated.
//It happens only in 3.1


-(NSTimeInterval )setTimeInterval:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] ;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy 00:00:00"];
    NSString *currStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    NSDate *newCurrentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currStr];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [newCurrentDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return timeInterval;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to get rid of this.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Comment: What value is warrObj.expiredOn?  What does setReverseDate do?

Comment: Its a date string.SetReverseDate converts the date string to NSDate to our required date format.

Comment: Got solved the problem.The space in the dateformatter created all the damage.Now I used [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"]; instead of  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy 00:00:00"];
 Now its working fine :)

Comment: Thanks to all for spending ur valuable time..!!

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeInterval` is just a `typedef` for `double`, it is not an object:

Getting a time interval:

```
NSTimerInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];


NSDate *expiryDate = [appDelegate setReverseDate:warrObj.expiredOn];
NSTimeInterval expiryInterval = [expiryDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Creating a date from a time interval:

```
NSTimeInterval oneHour = 60*60;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInterval - oneHour];
```

Comment: How can I convert the expiry date into timeInterval?